# Infinite loop warning in Vue even after removing all items

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel-blade, with vue2 running php 8.

I'm brand new to Vue and I'm sort of stumbling my way through the dark here. I'm basically working on a personal project, and I'm attempting to code 'filter buttons' that render themselves dynamically by looping through my JSON endpoint, extracting the title value, forming a brand new array, filtering the new array to remove duplicate values, then rendering them with a V-for.

This is my code:

```
<script>


  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        list: [],
        buttons: [],
        uniqueTitles: [],
        uniq : [],
      }
    },
    created() {
      axios.get('comic/search')
        .then(response => this.list = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

      axios.get('comic/search')
        .then(response => this.buttons = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                  
    },
    watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
      buttons() {
          this.buttons.forEach(element => {
          this.uniqueTitles.push(element.title)
          
          return this.uniqueTitles            
        });
      }, 
      uniqueTitles() {
        this.uniq = [...new Set(this.uniqueTitles)]
      }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
      axiosRequest(data) {
        console.log(data)
        axios.get(`comic/search?query=${data}`)
        .then(response => this.list = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
      onClickChild (value) {
          axiosRequest(value)
      },
      searchUpdate(search) {
        this.axiosRequest(search)
      },

      
    }
  }
</script>
```

and this is the PHP blade file

```
    @extends('site.layouts.default')

{{-- Update the Meta Title --}}
@section('meta_title')
{{ $page->getMetaTitle() }} | @parent{{""}}@stop

{{-- Update the Meta Description --}}
@section('meta_description'){{ $page->getMetaDescription() }}@stop

{{-- Update the Meta Description --}}
@section('meta_keywords'){{ $page->meta_keywords }}@stop

@if($page->status_id == 3)
  @section('robots')
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
  @stop
@endif

{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')



<div class="site-container px-6 md:px-0">
  <div class>
    <h1 class="type-4xl">{{ $page->title }}</h1>
    {!! $page->bodytext !!}
  </div>
      <Books inline-template>
      <div>
        <div class="flex overflow-scroll">
          <div v-for="title in uniq">
              <div class="flex mb-4">
                <button class="scaler mr-4 w-32 md:w-48 last:mr-0 px-4 flex justify-center items-center uppercase type-sm md:type-lg hover:cursor-pointer temp-hover p-2 rounded-lg border-2 border-black bg-black text-white" @click="axiosRequest(title)">@{{title}}</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Csearch @clicked="axiosRequest"></Csearch>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap align-middle">
        
        <li class="w-3/12 md:w-auto pt-0 md:p-4 list-none" v-for="(comic, index) in list.reverse()">
          <a :href="comic.url">
            {{-- desktop --}}
            <div class="hidden md:inline-block flip-container-comic md:mb-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
              <div class="flipper-comic">
                <div class="front-comic">
                  <div class="md:w-auto">
                    <div v-if="comic.front" class="relative pr-2 pt-2 pb-2 md:p-0">
                      <img class="w-full h-auto" :src="comic.front" :alt="comic.title">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back-comic">
                  <img class="w-full h-auto" :src="comic.rear" :alt="comic.title">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{-- desktop end --}}
            {{-- mobile --}}
            <div class="md:hidden md:mb-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div class="md:w-auto">
                    <div v-if="comic.front" class="relative pr-2 pt-2 pb-2 md:p-0">
                      <img class="w-full h-auto" :src="comic.front" :alt="comic.title">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back-comic">
                  <img class="w-full h-auto" :src="comic.rear" :alt="comic.title">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{-- mobile end --}}
          </a>
          <div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <div class="flex">
                  <div class="w-6/12">
                    <div class="hidden font-bold p-1 pr-8 text-left uppercase md:flex flex-col type-sm md:type-base">
                      <span>@{{comic.title}}</span><span> #@{{comic.issue}}</span> <span class="hidden md:inline">(@{{comic.published}})</span></div>
                    <div class="hidden md:flex flex-col">
                      <div class="hidden md:inline p-1 pr-8 text-left whitespace-nowrap uppercase">£@{{comic.price}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-6/12">
                    <form class="mt-4" method="post" action="/basket/add-product">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" :value="comic.id">
                      <input class="scaler hidden md:inline-block hover:cursor-pointer temp-hover px-4 py-2 rounded-xl border-2 border-black bg-black text-white" type="submit" value="+ Basket">
                     
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Books>

</div>



@stop
```

I get three separate infinite loop warnings, and I've tried generic debugging by removing each section and seeing if the issue vanishes, but even with everything commented out there is still one warning.

I apologise if my code is a mess, I'm literally like a blind man trying to solve a visual puzzle at this point.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `I get three separate infinite loop warnings` on which line of your code?

Comment: I wonder if your data `list` mutating in `(comic, index) in list.reverse()` is the issue ... try `(comic, index) in [...list].reverse()` - or even `this.list = response.data.reverse()` where you get the list in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX - you're amazing. That was it. I didn't even think to check the V-for loop itself, I was concentrating on the vue file. Thank you so much, this was driving me insane.